# React useRef / useEffect - Stop effect running on 1st render

Tags: reactjs

I have a useEffect hook that I want to run everytime the dependency `success` changes. My thinking is to put the dependency in the array which I believe to be correct.

However, this effect runs when the component mounts. I have read I can use a ref to help me solve this but I can't seem to implement it and the component still renders. Any thought?

```
    const isMounted = useRef(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
            fetchData();
        } else {
            isMounted.current = true;
        }
    }, [success]);
```

Comment: In this code fetchData() is fired on first render ?

Answer (score 1):

the code you supplied seems ok and gives "started, mounting, started, mounted" to console.

```
function App() {

    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

    const isMounted = useRef(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('started');
        if (isMounted.current) {
            console.log('mounted');
        } else {
            console.log('mounting');
            isMounted.current = true;
        }
    }, [success]);

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        setSuccess(!success);
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <button className="button" onClick={handleClick}>Action</button>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your component is wrapped in React.StrictMode, the effect will `fire -> cleanup -> fire` every time in development, to ensure there's nothing not being cleaned up correctly. You could try disabling StrictMode (since that doesn't run in production anyway) and see if the issue still happens.

The general React guidance is just to accept that things like data fetching will run twice in development (or with an attempt to avoid running on the first render, once instead of zero times).

See https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects for more information.

https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development also discusses some common scenarios and how to deal with them, although I think yours is one where the answer is to just let it happen in development.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the full code of your component to be sure nothing runs?

Here's a working example with the code you supplied (assuming this is what you wanted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/example-ts882o?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function fetchData() {
  console.log("fetching");
}

export default function App() {
  const isMounted = React.useRef(false);
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(true);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
      fetchData();
    } else {
      isMounted.current = true;
    }
  }, [success]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => setSuccess(!success)}
        style={{ backgroundColor: success ? "green" : "red" }}
      >
        toggle change
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```